# vb.net - geckofx45 how to ignore "site.com uses an invalid security certificate" error

Tags: vb.net, security, browser, certificate, geckofx

**am using geckofx45 in vb.net** made an app and used it fine then all of a sudden i start getting ***"site.com uses an invalid security certificate" "SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_ISSUER_CERTIFICATE"*** error message (even though it works fine in firefox) then doesnt procede to the website, tried copying the cert txt file from firefox profile to gecko but nothing.

if anyone knows **the commande to just ignore all certificates check in gecko** it would be very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update to GeckoFx 60 from your NuGet Package Manager

/> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geckofx60.64/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).